# Which design pattern is appriopriate for this situation?

Tags: c++, class, oop, design-patterns

I'm writing my program in C++11. I have a main class called *MyExperiment*. In this class there is another class, *ReadFromAFile*, which reads out some information about the set-up from a file. Then I want to use the data to initialise some other object which are members of the *MyExperiment* class. This is how it should look like:

```
class MyExperiment
{
    FirstObject *firstObject;
    SecondObject *secondObject;
public:
    MyExperiment()
    {
        ReadFromAFile readfromafile;
        readfromafile.read();
        firstObject = new FirstObject(/*some data from the readfromafile object */);
        secondObject = new SecondObject(/*some data from the readfromafile object */);
    }
}
```

Each *object* (*firstObject* and *secondObject*) class consists of some information that can (and should) be read out from a file and of some other variables and functions. I really **don't** want to have two classes for each object type: one for the data that can be read from the file and the other for the rest.

So, I want to read some infromation from a file using the ReadFromAFile class and then somehow pass the information to the construtors of my *objects*. My question is: what is the right way to do it?

Right now I have some structures which describe the data that I read from a file in the *ReadFromAFile* class. Each structure refers to one object. I have also getters functions which are invoked in the constructor of the *MyExperiment* class:

```
class MyExperiment
{
    FirstObject *firstObject;
    SecondObject *secondObject;
public:
    MyExperiment()
    {
        ReadFromAFile readfromafile;
        readfromafile.read();
        firstObject = new FirstObject(readfromafile.getFirstStruct());
        secondObject = new SecondObject(readfromafile.getSecondStruct());
    }
}
```

I don't think this solution is elegant and smart. I have a structure which depicts my *firstObject* and then I use it the constructor of this object.

I have no idea how to do it in a better way, so I'll be grateful for any remarks.

I don't want to read the file in my *myExperiment* class, because it's already complicated, so I need some enacpsulation.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more, but I would consider eliminating ReadFromAFile, and putting that functionality directly into first and second object. Just my two cents...

Answer (score 3):

`MyExperiment` does not depend on a file. It depends on `FirstObject` and `SecondObject`; have its constructor reflect that:

```
class MyExperiment {
  public:
    MyExperiment(FirstObject fo, SecondObject so)
     : fo(fo), so(so) { }
  private:
    FirstObject fo;
    SecondObject so;
};
```

Now you have removed any dependencies between `MyExperiment` and the manner in which the `First` and `Second` objects are read.

Now you can create some factory functions. For example, to make an experiment from a file you could do something like this:

```
MyExperiment make_experiment(std::string file) {
 ReadFromAFile stuff(file);
 return MyExperiment(stuff.fist_object(), stuff.second_object());
}
```

Finally, `ReadFromAFile` is a horrible name for a class. Probably you mean `FileReader` (possible a sub-class of a more general `DataSource` base class). In general, class names should be nouns and its methods should be verbs. You can, of course, name them whatever you want. But the `noun`-`verb` guideline does help you form a well-defined mental model of your system.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you want a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)). To not repeat yourself and drop 'structs' you can let your Reader class just construct objects, like this

```
firstObject = readfromafile.NewFirstObject();
secondObject = readfromafile.NewSecondObject();
```

Then you can declare the Reader FirstObject's and SecondObject's friend and make their constructors private, but that's not actually required.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to define separate classes and (I'm assuming that) you have few strategies for initialization, then I'd prefer to make a constructor that takes the an enum to choose the strategy for initialization, such as:

```
typedef enum _Strategy 
{
    STRATEGY_A = 1,
    STRATEGY_B
}

class MyExperiment
{
    FirstObject *firstObject;
    SecondObject *secondObject;
    public:
        MyExperiment()
        {
            firstObject = new FirstObject(STRATEGY_A);
            secondObject = new SecondObject(STRATEGY_B);
    }
}
```

and do the file reading and initialization according to the given strategy as @H. Gujit wrote in his comment.